# upnp: Get Content from MediaServer Device without AVTransport Service

Tags: service, media, sony, upnp, dlna

I want to download Images from a Sony NEX-6 Camera that supports DLNA. Discovering the ConnectionManager will return this:

```
<device
    xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <dlna:X_DLNADOC
        xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">DMS-1.50
    </dlna:X_DLNADOC>
    <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1</deviceType>
    <friendlyName>NEX-6</friendlyName>
    <manufacturer>Sony Corporation</manufacturer>
    <manufacturerURL>http://www.sony.com/</manufacturerURL>
    <modelDescription>SonyDigitalMediaServer</modelDescription>
    <modelName>SonyImagingDevice</modelName>
    <modelURL>http://www.sony.net/</modelURL>
    <UDN>uuid:00000000-0000-0010-8000-2002af0fa742</UDN>
    <serviceList>
        <service>
            <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1</serviceType>
            <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ContentDirectory</serviceId>
            <SCPDURL>/CdsDesc.xml</SCPDURL>
            <controlURL>/upnp/control/ContentDirectory</controlURL>
            <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/ContentDirectory</eventSubURL>
        </service>
        <service>
            <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1</serviceType>
            <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ConnectionManager</serviceId>
            <SCPDURL>/CmsDesc.xml</SCPDURL>
            <controlURL>/upnp/control/ConnectionManager</controlURL>
            <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/ConnectionManager</eventSubURL>
        </service>
    </serviceList>
    <iconList>
        <icon>
            <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
            <width>48</width>
            <height>48</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/DLNA_camera_48.jpg</url>
        </icon>
        <icon>
            <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
            <width>120</width>
            <height>120</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/DLNA_camera_120.jpg</url>
        </icon>
        <icon>
            <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
            <width>48</width>
            <height>48</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/DLNA_camera_48.png</url>
        </icon>
        <icon>
            <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
            <width>120</width>
            <height>120</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/DLNA_camera_120.png</url>
        </icon>
    </iconList>
    <av:standardCDS
        xmlns:av="urn:schemas-sony-com:av">5.0
    </av:standardCDS>
    <av:photoRoot
        xmlns:av="urn:schemas-sony-com:av">PhotoRoot
    </av:photoRoot>
</device>
```

As far as I can see, this Camera doesn't offer a AVTransport Service. Is that true? So how can I get the Images from the Camera? The max. Resolution from the ContentDirectory Service is way too small (`JPEG_LRG`).

Comment: You must have confused things here: AVTransport is a service provided by a renderer (e.g. a television). A camera with AVTransport doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Reading this: http://upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-MediaServer-v1-Device.pdf it tells: "MediaServer:1 products must implement minimum version numbers of all required embedded devices and services specified in the table below." ContentDirectory:1.0 (required), ConnectionManager:1.0 (required) AVTransport:1.0 (optional) So it's optional. the question is: How to I get the resource stream from the camera? Otheresie, I think I would use AVTransport: "This [AVTransport] instance is used by the Control Point to control the flow (e.g. Play, FF, REW, Seek, etc) of the content to the network."

Comment: AVTransport does not do what you want: it only allows you to control playback on the device, not fetch the actual media. ContentDirectory is the service that should do what you are asking for (but might not support huge images as you imply).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark I could capture the traffic.
Most of the requests are "standard" ContentDirectory requests like getting folder list, files, preview images a.s.o.
But as soon as I download a full image, I'm getting a request like this:

```
GET http://10.0.0.1:60151/LRG__DSC9978.ARW?%2104%5f02%5f1107310400%5f000002%5f000073%5f000000%21http%2dget%3a%2a%3aimage%2fjpeg%3aDLNA%2eORG%5fPN%3dJPEG%5fLRG%3bDLNA%2eORG%5fCI%3d1%21%21%21%21%21 HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; HUAWEI G510-0100 Build/HuaweiG510-0100)
Host: 10.0.0.1:60151
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

This will return the image data as JPEG in 1616 x 1080 pixel size ... whohoo. Decoding the GET request returns:

```
!04_02_1107310400_000002_000073_000000!http-get:*:image/jpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=JPEG_LRG;DLNA.ORG_CI=1!!!!!
```

Now I have to see how to build up this query string. Seems not to be standardized to me. If someone has a clue, let me know.

Comment: Ok, first thing is the `ObjectID` the file name is given by the `ContentDirectory` service and the rest seems to be some static settings. Dunno why they are separated by `!` and not used like "normal" `GET` parameter (eg. `LRG__DSC9978.ARW?ObjectID=04_02_1107310400_000002_000073_000000&...`). But I think I've all info to get the images. :) Thx for everyone who tried to help!

If you do have some further info, like if this is standardized somewhere, let me know!

Comment: Hi Andre! I know this is going a way back, but did you ever manage to figure out how this is all working? I'm trying to make an app which does similar to this!

Answer (score -1):

Actually, rather than DLNA/UPnP, Sony Digital Camera is controlled by `Wirelessly access Sony cameras with the Camera Remote API beta` which is based on HTTP and JSON.

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Hope that will help.

Comment: I heard about that, thanks. But sadly, I can't use the `Camera Remote API` because I'm running the app on Firefox OS, that only supports JavaScript. Any hints how to get the source URL without using the Camera Remote API would be very appreciated. Accessing the ContentDirectory Service works great so far, no only the part with downloading a full resolution image is missing. And I have no clue how to do this (and can't intercept the camera traffic).

Comment: The linked page implies the service is a JSON one. What is the problem with using that from javascript?